# how to update dataGrid in database

Tags: c#

In my C# project, i populated the values in DataGrid from DataTable. Now if i make changes in the values in the DataGrid i need to update them in the DataBase. I'm using MS access.
Here is the code snippet of how i populate values in the DataGrid.

```
                    while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    frmBind.dr = frmBind.dtResults.NewRow();
                    frmBind.dr["ClassName"] = myReader.GetString(0);

                    frmBind.dr["MethodSignature"] = myReader.GetString(1);

                    frmBind.dr["ParameterValues"] = myReader.GetString(2);
                    frmBind.dr["ExpectedResults"] = myReader.GetString(3);


                    frmBind.dtResults.Rows.Add(frmBind.dr);

                }

                frmBind.dataGrid2.DataSource = frmBind.dtResults;
```

where, 
dtResults is DataTable, 
frmBind is a Class Object,
dataGrid2 is the DataGrid,
myReader.Read() is used to get the values from the DataBase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you drop the datareader.

Drag an SQLDataSource onto the page and configure it with your query.  It will give you reading/updating without writing any code at all.

Comment: No, the OP is using Access and (most likely) WinForms.

Comment: My Apologies - Henk is correct.  I saw DataGrid and thought GridView.  Been doing too many WebForms recently.